# Save UI control/page state

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, desktop-application

We have an app with chat style like the Telegram Desktop: in the right part of the window the correspondents list, in the left side - the grouped by date list of the dialog messages with the selected correspondent. Now we use Dictionary for save current state of every dialog with correspondent.
By selecting correspondent we took exist control for display dialog, or create new, and bind it to ContentPresenter:

```
    <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.DetailsDialog, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

After three or more Controls added to the dictionary, UI starts freezing (scrolling disabled etc), memory and processor is not overloaded(something about 6% of processor, and 50 mb of RAM).

So my question is how can we achieve the best performance with saving UI state of control or page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the UI elements which are resource expensive, it is usually better to store state in view model classes which contain all data and then use data-binding to bind the state data to a "fresh" new UI instance instead.

Comment: I was trying the approach you propose, couple iterations ago, but met difficulties with scrolling grouped list to specific position. Could you provide some examples of saving UI state  in view model?